# How can I automate Q&N import?

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker, language-studio

Using Lanaguage Studio, I manaully export my Questions and Answers from one environment and import them into another environment.

Is there a way to auotmate this?
The langauge studio API has endpoints to get the answers, but I can't find one that will do the export or the import.

I would like to use a powershell module, but I don't see these featrures in the Az.CognitiveServices module.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cognitiveservices/?view=azps-11.2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve and update questions and answers for the provided project using the **[Authoring API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/question-answering/how-to/authoring)**.

To get question and answer pairs, use the following [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/question-answering/how-to/authoring#get-question-answer-pairs) request.

`curl -X GET -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {API-KEY}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" 'https://{ENDPOINT}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/language/query-knowledgebases/projects/{PROJECT-NAME}/qnas?api-version=2021-10-01'`

For updates, use the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/question-answering/how-to/authoring#update-question-and-answer-pairs) request below.

```
curl -X PATCH -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {API-KEY}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "value":{
            "id": 1,
            "answer": "The latest question answering docs are on https://learn.microsoft.com",
            "source": "source5",
            "questions": [
                "Where do I find docs for question answering?"
            ],
            "metadata": {},
            "dialog": {
                "isContextOnly": false,
                "prompts": []
            }
        }
    }
]'  -i 'https://{ENDPOINT}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/language/query-knowledgebases/projects/{PROJECT-NAME}/qnas?api-version=2021-10-01'
```

Here, the idea is to get details from one environment and update them in another environment using this curl request.

You can also import and export the project itself instead of questions and answers. Here is the reference for it. [Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/question-answering/how-to/authoring#export-project-metadata-and-assets) gives you the URI, which is used further to [import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/question-answering/how-to/authoring#import-project).